# How does value effect val()?

Tags: jquery

I am able to set the selected item in an html `select` item using jQuery's `val()` function.  [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/Pa4Pa/6/),

```
<select id="selector">
    <option></option>
    <option>Care Bears</option>
    <option>Yo Gabba Gabba</option>
</select>

<input id="selectButton" type="button" value="Care Bears" />
```

---

```
$('#selectButton').click(function() {
    $('#selector').val('Care Bears');//change the selected value to care bears
});
```

But, if I [modify](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/Pa4Pa/7/) the code slightly,

`<option value="">Care Bears</option>`

`val()` breaks.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no longer an `<option/>` that matches `"Care Bears"` in the `value` attribute.

HTML defaults the `value` attribute of the `<option/>` tag to the Contents, if not otherwise specified.

This is actually part of the Javascript Spec as noted in the comment below.

**[Example to show vanilla javascript functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/Pa4Pa/10/)**

Comment: That's interesting, why don't we see this default in FireBug? Yet, somehow jQuery seems to be smart enough to see it. Are you sure it's not that jQuery first checks for the existence of a value attribute and then falls back on the inner text?

Comment: Take server side form submissions for example, if you don't specify a `value` it falls back on the inner text.

Comment: Its in the spec: The value attribute provides a value for element. The value of an option element is the value of the value attribute, if there is one, or the textContent of the element, if there isn't. (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-option-element)

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="value">not important text</option>
when you set a value this option's value is setted.
if you dont set, its not important text will be its value
```

becouse

```
<option>Care Bears</option>
equal
<option value="Care Bears">Care Bears</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not breaking because it checks for the value of `Care Bears`. Currently the value  is empty.

```
<option value="">Care Bears</option>
```

Now it looks for the empty value on the list and selects that item.

That is the reason why it is selecting the empty the value.

As already told by jondavid and utku,

both are equal

```
<option>Care Bears</option>

<option value="Care Bears">Care Bears</option>
```